# TypeError: in Python

Tags: python

I have an issue, where a function returns a number.  When I then try to assemble a URL that includes that number I am met with failure.

Specifically the error I get is

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Not sure where to go from here.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
# Get the raw ID number of the current configuration
configurationID = generate_configurationID()

# Update config name at in Cloud
updateConfigLog = open(logBase+'change_config_name_log.xml', 'w')
# Redirect stdout to file
sys.stdout = updateConfigLog
rest.rest(('put', baseURL+'configurations/'+configurationID+'?name=this_is_a_test_', user, token))
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

It works perfectly if I manually type the following into rest.rest()

```
rest.rest(('put', http://myurl.com/configurations/123456?name=this_is_a_test_, myusername, mypassword))
```

I have tried `str(configurationID)` and it spits back a number, but I no longer get the rest of the URL...

Ideas?  Help?

OK...   In an attempt to show my baseURL and my configurationID here is what I did.

```
print 'baseURL: '+baseURL
print 'configurationID: '+configurationID
```

and here is what I got back

```
it-tone:trunk USER$ ./skynet.py fresh
baseURL: https://myurl.com/
369596
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./skynet.py", line 173, in <module>
    main()
  File "./skynet.py", line 30, in main
    fresh()
  File "./skynet.py", line 162, in fresh
    updateConfiguration()
  File "./skynet.py", line 78, in updateConfiguration
    print 'configurationID: '+configurationID
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
it-tone:trunk USER$
```

What is interesting to me is that the 369596 is the config ID, but like before it seems to clobber everything called up around it.

As kindall pointed out below, my generate_configurationID was not *returning* the value, but rather it was printing it.

```
# from generate_configurationID
def generate_configurationID():
  dom = parse(logBase+'provision_template_log.xml')
  name = dom.getElementsByTagName('id')
  p = name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
  print p
  return p
```

Comment: **Read the error message.** And then try a minimal test-case: `"hello" + None` -- what happens? The answer is "you have None where you don't expect it" (now go find out where/why). Please update the title to make it relevant/useful as well.

Comment: Show us: 1. your attempt with `str(configurationID)` 2. baseURL 3. the complete error message, including the line numbers it complains about.

Comment: I don't really know how else to day this...   I don't know how to concatenate these pieces, and I don't know enough to figure out what is not going right here.   I did read the error message.   I don'g understand how "none" can even show up.  These variables are defined.  what undefined them?  I thought objects could not be destroyed in Python.  Once defined they were defined for the duration.   Not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `configurationID` is `None`. This likely means that `generate_configurationID()` is not returning a value. There is no way in Python for a variable name to "lose" its value. The only way, in the code you posted, for `configurationID` to be `None` is for `generate_configurationID()` to return `None` which is what will happen if you don't explicitly return any value.

"But it prints the `configurationID` right on the screen!" you may object. Sure, but that's probably in `generate_configurationID()` where you are printing it to make sure it's right but forgetting to return it.

You may prove me wrong by posting `generate_configurationID()` in its entirety, and I will admit that your program is **magic**.